# Incomplete ListViews for CrossReference

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I am using Word 2010 and have to often insert cross-references. Items to be cross-referenced are mostly table numbers and figure numbers, such as Talbe 1-2 or Figures 2-4. They always include chapter numbers. I want to simplify this cross-reference procedure using Macro which functions as follows:

1. A User Form with Option Buttons will appear for me to specify Table or Figure. (For example, I will choose Table.)
2. Then, a list of all the tables in the document will appear using a User Form with List View.
3. I will scroll the list and choose one that I want to refer. For example, I will choose Table 3-4.
4. "Table 3-4" (label and number) will be inserted.

I wrote a VBA script as follows. It consists of one standard module and two form modules.

The standard module looks as follows.

```
Option Explicit
Public refLabel As String
'
Sub CrossReference()
    Load frmLabel
    frmLabel.Show
    Call Form
End Sub

Private Sub Form()
    MsgBox "Please specify the　” & refLabel & " number to be cross referenced."
    Load frmCrossRef
    frmCrossRef.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

One of the form module for "frmLabel", which has one command button and two option buttons, is as below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If OptionButton1 = True Then
        refLabel = OptionButton1.Caption
    ElseIf OptionButton2 = True Then
        refLabel = OptionButton2.Caption
    End If
    frmLabel.Hide
End Sub
```

Option Button 1 is for "Table" and Option Button 2 is for "Figure". By this user form, refLabel is "Table" or "Figure", depending on which option was chosen.

Another form module for "frmCrossRef" is as below. The form has one ListView and one Command Button.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ListView1
        .View = lvwReport
        .LabelEdit = lvwManual
        .HideSelection = False
        .AllowColumnReorder = True
        .Gridlines = True
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , "_Outline", refLabel, 200
        .FullRowSelect = True
    End With

    items = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(refLabel)

    For Each Item In items
        ListView1.ListItems.Add , , Item
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    ind = ListView1.SelectedItem.Index

    Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=refLabel, _
        ReferenceKind:=wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, _
        ReferenceItem:=ind, InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

It looks work as I expected, but the ListView does not show complete list of tables or figures. Although there are about 20 tables or figures, the list shows only few.

I hope anyone can correct the script.

Thank you.

Comment: You would probably be better off posting this on StackOverflow, but it looks as if there is a problem with Word rather than your code - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949516/problem-with-getcrossreferenceitems-in-msword-and-vba

Comment: Thank you for the link. The site does not really answer to my question, but I have got a hint to further explore the web and finally I reached here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1649403. The approach was different, but the procedure was just what I wanted. I will close this thread.